# Программа для замера фпс на сайте

Tags: javascript

Подскажите программу для проверки фпс на сайте. Вроде должен быть такой инструмент для браузера, который показывает производительность сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В браузерах уже встроены:

- Chrome [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks)
- FireFox [Web Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance)